# Reading a parameter and running a program with it in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Ok, so I know to run an .exe in batch you use START.  However, let me explain how the .exe works.

Let's say I have it in `C:\`, and it's called uptime.exe.

I would go to Run and bring up cmd and navigate to C: then type into CMD the following: `uptime.exe computername`.

However, to run it, I always have to go through those steps of going into cmd prompt and typing in `uptime.exe computername`.

I wanted to create a batch file that would prompt the username and attach that to starting the .exe but my attempts have failed.

This is what I have:

```
@echo off
color 0E
:start
SET /P pcname=Type in Computer's Name: 
echo.
start "c:\windows\system32" uptime.exe /%pcname%
echo.
ECHO Press any key to close this window.
pause>nul
```

Comment: What result are you expecting and what result are you receiving?

Comment: Also, is there any reason you need the `:start` label?

Answer (score 1):

start "Some title - may be empty" "c:\windows\system32\uptime.exe" /%pcname%

should get you off the ground. I've assumed that `uptime.exe` is in `c:\windows\system32`, but you say it's in `c:\` - which is confusing.

start "Some title - may be empty" "c:\uptime.exe" /%pcname%

would be the case if `uptime.exe` truly is in `c:\`

if `uptime.exe` is somewhere on the `path` then

start "Some title - may be empty" uptime.exe /%pcname%

is all that is required - and the quoted parameter becomes optional.

To see `PATH`, simply type `path` at the prompt. The `path` variable contains a <kbd>;</kbd>-separated sequence of directorynames which are searched in order when the system wants to find an executable that isn't in the current (aka "logged") directory.